# Importerror on win32ui for 32 bit Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to run a bot for Super Hexagon (Just for fun), but when I try to run the module in IDLE 2.7.11 (32 bit) I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last) :
>
> File "C:\Users(Me)\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 8, in < module >
>
> ```
>   import win32ui
> ```
>
> ImportError: No module named win32ui

Unfortunately, right now I'm streaming my desktop to my Macbook, so I can't copy the code, [but here's an image of the part the program has an error with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNTXf.png)

I have 64 bit Windows 8, so the win32ui is most likely the problem, but I'm not sure how to change the code to accomodate 64 bit. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not the the BIT version from your Windows PC.

It seems to me, that you have not installed he module win32ui.

After searching the web, I have found, the module pywin32, which should include all necessary WIN thinks.
You can install it via pip, easy_install of with these MSI installer:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

Please use the newest and correct version.

But I think you have to change the code:
Sorry I have no Windows PC, so I could not try it, maybe something like that:

```
from pywin32 import *
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the Python libraries you are using here, is causing the issue. There is 64 bit build for python win32ui.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

Download and install one of then and set the build path and import accordingly.